# Show that $F(\Sigma_1)(\Sigma_2) = F(\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/F$ where $K$ is the field extension of $F$, and $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2 \subset K$

Show that $F(\Sigma_1)(\Sigma_2) = F(\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2)$.

I have an argument but I can't help but feel that my idea is too.... naive.

The idea is to show that generator of one side is contain in the other.

But $F(\Sigma_1)(\Sigma_2) = F(\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2)$

Then simply by "eye-balling" isnt it obvious ?

Is there something wrong with my chain of thoughts, if so please do point it out.

Thank you

Comment: What are $K,F,\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$? Otherwise the question is lacking context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume $K/F$ is a field extension. Your idea is correct, but you need to execute the argument more carefully.

Firstly, $F(\Sigma_1)(\Sigma_2)$ is a subfield of $K$ containing $F$ which also contains both $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. Therefore $F(\Sigma_1)(\Sigma_2) \supseteq F(\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2)$.

On the other hand, $F(\Sigma_1)(\Sigma_2)$ is the smallest subextension of $K/F(\Sigma_1)$ which contains $\Sigma_2$. Since $F(\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2)$ is such a subextension, $F(\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2) \supseteq F(\Sigma_1)(\Sigma_2)$.

We therefore have equality.